# Using variables for button names

Tags: excel, loops, variables, button

I am trying to hide or make visible a large amount of buttons in an excel file. The button visibility is depending on the cell next to the button. If the cell is empty, the button is hidden. If the cell has content, the button is visible. The code for that is pretty straightforward, for instance:

```
If Range("B202").Value <> "" Then
    

Me.CommandButton2.Visible = True

Else
    

Me.CommandButton2.Visible = False

End If
```

The sub is being triggered based on changing a cell on the worksheet:
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Instead of copying the code for the buttons tens of times and changing the range value as well as the button number, I'd like to have that done in a loop instead. Changing the range in a for/next loop has not created any issue, however, I was not successful in assigning the button name in a dynamic way. Note that my buttons are numbered in a sequential way, i.e. this would fit a loop approach.
Thanks for your thoughts!

Tried the following:

```
For i = 1 To 2
  

c = "B20" & i
  

j = i + 1
  

If Range(c).Value <> "" Then
    

me.Controls("CommandButton" & j).Visible = True
  

Else
    

me.Controls("CommandButton" & j).Visible = False
  

End If

Next
```

Comment: If the buttons are on a sheet (and this design sounds horrible to me) then there is no `Controls` collection to work with. Use` Shapes` or `OLEObjects`

Comment: Thanks Rory, this did the job. Indeed, the buttons are on a sheet. True, once a row is added, the whole thing is messed up. Any suggestions on how to improve this are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want all those buttons on a sheet in the first place?